# Content-Type header not getting set in Apache Camel

Tags: routes, http-headers, apache-camel

I'm having some problems with setting the Content Type on an outgoing request made with Camel routes.
The purpose is to validate an account ID with a statement ID and if there's a match, it will go through a processor to a downloadable link that gives you a PDF back. If validation is unsuccessful then it should throw an error and return a JSON object.

The project goes through a service and a library, the first part of code is just routing to the 2nd part that performs the logic. Here are the two routes:

```
             .rest("some_path")
//           .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
             .get("some_other_path")
             .param(accountId)
             .param(statementId)
             .route()
                 .setProperty(accountId.getName(), header(accountId.getName()))
                 .setProperty(statementId.getName(), header(statementId.getName()))
            .endRest();
```

which will route to this:

```
            from(previous_some_path))
                .process(DownloadProcessor)
                .choice()
                    .when(IDisMatching)
                        .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF))
                        .toD("${property.download-url}") 
                        .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF))
                    .otherwise()
                        .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                        .process(ErrorProcessor)
                    .endChoice()
                .end();
```

The errorthrowing works fine when testing (it catches the error and gives back JSON) but whenever I try testing with matching ID's which will route to .toD("${property.download-url}") and return a PDF, the connection times out. My guess is it's because Camel expects something else than a PDF (a default JSON/xml value perhaps?)

I've tried:

- using getOut instead of getIn
- using .consumes together with .produces
- setting the header at multiple places in the code. It simply does not register it when returning the output

Anyone have any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong? Is there a hierarchy going on in the background where Content-Type is set automatically to a default value. Or do I need to set two content-types, if so how? etc etc.

Would very much appreciate the input!
Thanks

Comment: What is a sample expected value for `${property.download-url}`? is it something like `https://somehost/some/where/pdf`? Are you trying to do an HTTP redirect in the case of success?

Comment: Exactly. I'm not actually doing anything in case of success.. not sure if there is any value in redirecting?